# Why Hibernate Throws Invalid Column Name Exception?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

my query runs in oracle but in my java code select wuery throws invalid column name.
my entity:

```
@Basic
@Column(name = "kasr_uni", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR2(100)")
private String kasr_uni;
```

my query class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ExportManagerImpl implements ExportManager {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List getAllUnis() {
        return entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT kasr_uni FROM KASR GROUP BY kasr_uni ORDER BY kasr_uni ASC",Kasr.class).getResultList();
    }
}
```

exception:

```
  java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:558)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:73)
org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:785)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:721)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
```

Comment: please add the full exception...

Comment: Try `"SELECT \"kasr_uni\" FROM KASR...`, does that work?

Comment: Why do you use a native query instead of a JPQL one? `group by` doesn't make sense either in this query: you don't have any aggregation (like count, sum, min, etc.).

Comment: @M.Deinum added some of exception.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller didnt work throws another exception.

Comment: @JBNizet removing group by didnt worked.

Comment: As mentioned by my first comment please add the **full** exception not just a snippet.

Comment: @M.Deinum stack doesnt allow me add full exception.wanna upload a text file?